# UIRefreshControl in wrong position when used in TabBarController item

Tags: ios, swift, uikit, tableview, uirefreshcontrol

I am developing an iOS application which has a "main" TabBarController with 7 view controllers.
Every view controller is a NavigationViewController with a TableViewController as its root.

Every TableViewController has a UIRefreshControl set up using storyboard.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.title = "12345678".localized

    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.tintColor = Customizer.getColor1()
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.prefersLargeTitles = true
    self.refreshControl?.tintColor = Customizer.getColor1()

    self.refreshControl?.beginRefreshing()
    self.doRefresh(0)
}

@IBAction func doRefresh(_ sender: Any) {
    let d : AppDelegate = self.appDelegate

    DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).async {

        BeautifulAPI().getBeautifulData(delegate: d) { (result: Result<[EBListItem]>) in
            switch result{
            case .success(let data):
                self.items = data

                self.done_loading()
                break
            case .failure(let statusCode, let error):
                print("Error \(statusCode) : \(String(describing: error))")

                break
            }
        }
    }
}
```

When the controller is in the tab bar, it behaves correctly: when i open the page, I see the loading spinner in the title of the table view.

When I need to pass through "More" page in the tab bar controller, it happens that the refresh spinner is between the title and the table rows. When it stops spinning and I trigger refresh, it gets in the correct position, but I still have a blank space between title and table rows.

Answer (score 0):

I answer my own question.

This has been discovered as a bug by Apple Code Level Support.